# Third party Class requires deprecated ActionBarActivity as a parameter

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to utilize a side-menu from a GitHub repo. The animation for the menu requires a Class `ViewAnimator` to take a parameter `ActionBarActivity`, given in the sample as `this` (i.e. the `MainActivity`, which extends `ActionBarActivity`).

Due to `ActionBarActivity` being deprecated, and my `MainActivity` extending `AppCompatActivity`, the statement shows an error.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: did you try using @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: You mean by extending ActionBarActivity instead of AppCompatActivity? I understand you can suppress deprecation warnings, but should we not attempt to use non-deprecated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Actually use ActionBarActivity.

2) Download the source code of the github repo, import it into your project (not by gradle, or as a .jar, i mean actual source code), and then modify the function to accept a AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity. (This would require testing to see if everything still worked as expected).

3) Make an issue on the github repo and hope the original developer can/will help you out by modifying the code.

You can't trick it into thinking it's getting an ActionBarActivity if that isn't what it's getting.

Comment: It's not ideal, and could lead into complications further down the road (a *very* long way down the road). But seeing as ActionBarActivity wasn't deprecated untill 2 months ago, i wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Okay, I'll do this for the time being then. Thanks. Will accept as answer shortly.